# Nextcord bot: Google detects virus?

Tags: pyinstaller, nextcord

I have an odd problem.  In the last few weeks I have switched from `discord.py` to `nextcord`.  The bot I have is trivial. It is based on Python 3.9.  A friend asked me to create it for his server.  I use `pinstaller` to create a Win-10 executable.  I bundle the `dist` result into a zip archive.  This is stored on a shared Google Drive.  Once on the shared drive Google flags it as containing a virus.

I have checked my primary linux desktop and the Win-10 VM, in which I build the executable.  No viruses detected.

This is a new problem for me.  I am not sure how to investigate this.  I am looking for pointers and advice.  I am not claiming that `nextcord` is the issue, it is just the newest item in the mix.

Comment: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/847 this might help you

Comment: Thanks.  That helped.  Turns out I was using `pyinstaller` 4.8. I rolled back to 4.7 and its fine now. Cheers

Comment: That's great. good luck!